# Setting Parity Check Matrix for LDPC channel coding

Tags: matlab, ofdm, channelcoding, ldpc

I am trying to implement the LDPC code for OFDM system, where I input data should be binary of length $1024$ and the output coded data of length $2048$ (means of rate 1/2).

As known in Matlab integrated function, we build the encoder and decoder, respectively, as:

```
ldpcEncoder = comm.LDPCEncoder;  %Encoder 
ldpcDecoder = comm.LDPCDecoder;  %Decoder
```

After checking that, I see that parity check matrix is set by default into $32400$ x $64800$ which means the input data length must be a column of length $32400$.

I need the input data to be set manually, for example of length $1024$, how can I modify the parity check of the above encoder?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe, you should try to build the ldpc manually using your own parameters.

Comment: Matlab doesn't have a default 32400 x 64800 size: you've entered that somewhere before. You're not showing us all of your code!

Comment: That's all what I entered, I only entered these two commands, and the resulted size is 32400 x 64800. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @Fatima_Ali these two lines don't output the size, so that **can't** be all you've done. Do a `clear`, then post all lines that you had to type to find out the size.

Comment: @MarcusMüller , I already did clear, I'm sure that gives that output,  and that gives that size output. I am using matlab 2019b  and I think that should be similar in all new versions of MATLAB.

Comment: These two lines do not print a size. How do you know the size of the code? What is it that you do to know the size? You're not including that in your quesiton.

Comment: @Fatima_Ali the documentation is clear https://fr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.ldpcencoder-system-object.html Specify `'ParityCheckMatrix'` in both encoder and decoder.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I see the see from the resultant variable, I can see its size, or I encode a message of that size and it works well, so I can know the size by that way.

Comment: @AlexTP Yes I checked that, but how can I specify the ParityCheckMatrix matrix ? Is it a random matrix including 0s and 1s  with any size I want ?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali I don't get it, why do you want random matrix? Do you have your PCM? If yes, put it to the field like specifying in the website page. In the same page, there is an example and default configuration for the DVB-S.2 standard. Check also function `dvbs2ldpc()` if you have doubt about the input format.

Comment: @AlexTP I don't mean it should be random matrix, I'm just wondering. I mean what should it be the input 'ParityCheckMatrix' ? Do you have any example for that with size, for example, 1024x2048  or for any other size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.ldpcencoder-system-object.html), using `'ParityCheckMatrix'` you can configure the Parity Check Matrix (PCM) during the constructions of the encoder/decoder objects.

The syntax is `encoder = comm.LDPCEncoder('ParityCheckMatrix',pcm)` or simply

```
encoder = comm.LDPCEncoder(pcm);
```

where `pcm` is the desired PCM which must be *sparse* type.

An example for (probably poor performance) 1024x2048 PCM:

```
pcm = sparse([eye(1024) eye(1024)]);
encoder = comm.LDPCEncoder(pcm);
decoder = comm.LDPCDecoder(pcm);

%data
m = randi([0 1],1024,1);
%encode then decode. Note the convention of the output of comm.LDPCDecoder
y = 1 - decoder(encoder(m));
%error which equals to 0
biterr(y,m)
```

Comment: Thank you for you help

Comment: @Fatima_Ali you are welcome